# rails: Authorize Hashtags (#) in forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, special-characters

I have a basic rails app that allow users to create pins - I want them to be able to put special characters like Hashtags (#) in the forms - but it doesn't render, however it works with special characters like at (@).

```
<div class="formjoin form form-group">
  <%= f.label :What_do_you_want_people_to_tweet? %>
  <%= f.text_area :tweet, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Tweet" %>
</div>
```

I was thinking of validating special characters, but I am not sure how to do that. Any recommendation ?

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel.
https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb

Comment: That makes no sense to use such a gem - as all I want is to validates characters like the number sign in my forms - I should use validates_forms with regex but it still doesn't render !